# How can I encrypt data in cloud storage services like Dropbox?

Tags: ubuntu-one, security, encryption, dropbox

I'd love to use Ubuntu One or Dropbox features, like file storage and so on, but I don't want anyone else to access my data, USA Patriot act etc.. I want things to be encrypted so that the only place where info is decrypted is only *my* devices. Is that possible with Ubuntu One or Dropbox?

Comment: One of Ubuntu One's purpose is to provide access to one's data from anywhere, any time. With encryption, that will not be possible. But I think making this encryption optional would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 32):

Yes it is possible. The best way to archive this with a per file encryption is with encfs:

The general principle is that you have a (optionally hidden) encrypted folder inside UbuntuOne/Dropbox where your files are stored, but you access them though another folder, where the decrypted files are shown. Any File you add to the decrypted folder will be encrypted and put into the encrypted folder:

Decrypted folder ←encfs→ Encrypted Folder (inside UbuntuOne/Dropbox)

On another computer the encrypted folder is synced by UbuntuOne/Dropbox and can also be decrypted on the fly.

**Installation:**

- Install encfs version 1.7 or greater

  ```
  sudo apt-get install encfs
  ```
- install [gnome-encfs-manager](http://www.libertyzero.com/GEncfsM/):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gencfsm/ppa
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-encfs-manager
  ```

**Setting up the Drive on the first computer:**

- Create a (hidden) directory inside Dropbox/Ubuntu One to use as for the encrypted files
- Start gnome-encfs-manager and set up a new stash (click on the plus sign)
- Set the directory to encrypt to a (hidden) folder inside your Dropbox/Ubuntu one folder
- Set the mount directory wherever you want (default is fine)
- enter a good password (30 random chars...) and click "Create"
- edit the new stash so it is mounted on startup and the password is saved in the gnome keyring

You should now have your encrypted drive mounted (it will be displayed like a mounted usb-drive)

**Importing the drive on other computers:**

- Wait for all files to sync
- Start gnome-encfs-manager and set up a new stash
- Set the directory to the previously created folder inside your Dropbox/Ubuntu
- encfs-manager will detect the drive and import it
- Set the mount directory wherever you want (default is fine) and click "Import"
- edit the new stash as desdribed above
- you will be asked for your password on first mount

**Cross Platform compatibility:**

- This is cross compatible with Android when using [Encdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mrpdaemon.android.encdroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm9yZy5tcnBkYWVtb24uYW5kcm9pZC5lbmNkcm9pZCJd) (open source, recommended) or [Cryptonite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNzaC5jcnlwdG9uaXRlIl0.) (open source). Both Android Apps support Dropbox and should also work with UbuntuOne using local folder decryption (in combination with an UbuntuOne client which syncs your files onto the SD Card)
- This is probably also compatible with windows using [encfs4win](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html) or other software.

Comment: This works well and should be marked as the accepted answer. The only downside when using this with Ubuntu One (not sure about DropBox) is that notifications and file syncing/checked icons don't appear so it's difficult to know when files have finished syncing to Ubuntu One.

Comment: With dropbox the syncing-icon works when using this method ;-)

Comment: Do you know why EncFS has slow write performance? It's much slower than ecryptfs or truecrypt. https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/cloudfs-devel/2011-June/000093.html

Comment: @gsedej I have no Idea, but it is more than fast enough for my purposes

Comment: @gsedej Do you have more up-to-date numbers? This latter mail in the same thread says that those numbers are for an early version and "performance is likely to get significantly worse (for CloudFS)"
https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/cloudfs-devel/2011-June/000103.html

This page has some more details:
http://wiki.excito.org/wiki/index.php/Using_encFS_on_the_B3#encFS_or_eCryptfs....3F

Comment: There have been security vulnerabilities found in Encfs that make it especially insecure when used with Dropbox, see [here](https://www.cryfs.org/comparison#encfs) . An alternative would be [CryFS](https://www.cryfs.org).

Answer (score 8):

The only good way to do this is to first encrypt the files locally, then move them to the Ubuntu One folder. If you make an encrypted partition or container and then choose to sync that with Ubuntu One, you risk syncing the unencrypted data. See [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/74734) for one approach using encFS. It has it's limitations though.

An alternative is [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/), which works like Ubuntu One but encrypts everything before it leaves your machine. They claim they have no way to recover your data if you forget your password, and it even has two-factor authentication. Last I tried it, it would slow down my machine for several minutes after booting while it scanned my drive, but this may have been fixed by now. Also, it's 2GB free vs Ubuntu One's free 5GB.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58821/how-safe-is-eu-based-ubuntu-one-cloud-data) is another Ask Ubuntu post detailing some of the issues you raise.

Answer (score 5):

I can propose you the **Wuala** service here: http://www.wuala.com/en as an alternative to Spideroak. Almost same functionalities.

But, if you really want to control the encryption yourself, I can propose you to use **Ubuntu One** and **Déjà-Dup** (backup tool) together. You use the server space of Ubuntu One for your data, but you upload the data through Déjà-Dup using a password. Déjà-Dup will encrypt the data with your password. I think this is the best solution: simple and secure.

Answer (score 4):

You could possibly make use of EncFS (http://www.arg0.net/encfs). Use the Ubuntu One directory to store the encrypted file system, while mounting it somewhere else. For example, using the following setup.

- `~/Ubuntu One/.encrypted` - the hidden encrypted files
- `~/Ubuntu One (encrypted)/` - the visible decrypted files

This however will make the number of files, directory and file structure, and their sizes visible, so it's not an ultimate solution.

Read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption) for more details of how to set it up, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS) for some basic information about advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 3):

I tried SpiderOak

**Pros**:
    "Zero knowledge" concept built in from the ground, exactly what I was looking for.

```
Super easy setup on Ubuntu and Android phone.

Concurrent file access AND encryption is there by design.
```

**Cons**:
    Closed source client. I trust open source more, when it comes to security.

```
Cannot synchronize mobile phone directories to the cloud. Con only read
what is stored, by downloading every file on demand.
```

I chose to go with UbuntuOne + EncFs, since encryption layer is open source.

Still, would very appreciate if UbuntuOne would implement "Zero Knowledge"
concept out of the box.

---

Now I'm using **SSHFS** against own server to access large files like
photo / video collection.

**pros**:
    No need to duplicate every file on every computer.

```
No monthly fees for keeping terabytes of data on the network.
(because it's all on my once bought hardware)
```

**cons**:
    Useless on slow network connections or when offline.

And I use **GIT + GITCOLA** for document registry.

**pros**:
    Can work offline.

```
Have history on previous directory/files states.
```

**cons**:
    Doesn't work well on binary files above 1 GB.

```
Space is consumed by local git repository AND checked out copy of files,
so not good for huge video / photo collections.
```

And I use UbuntuOne + EncFS for a few gigabytes of fast changing and temporary files, like Desktop directory. This way I can conveniently switch computers and continue working on the same in-progress files, even sometimes offline and without quickly growing GIT repository.

Answer (score 3):

## [CryFS](https://www.cryfs.org)

**DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the developers of the below project.**

---

There is a relatively new open source project called [Cryfs](https://www.cryfs.org) which was designed for encrypting your Dropbox (or other cloud storage).

It was built mainly because all existing encrypted file systems have their disadvantages when used with cloud storage.

- [Encfs is not secure](https://www.cryfs.org/comparison#encfs)
- [Truecrypt/Veracrypt causes high network load and synchronization conflicts](https://www.cryfs.org/comparison#veracrypt)
- [eCryptfs isn't designed for cloud storage either](https://www.cryfs.org/comparison#ecryptfs)

Furthermore, CryFS not only encrypts your file contents, but also file sizes, metadata and directory structure, which is not true for the other tools except VeraCrypt.

Not encrypting your file sizes and directory structure can give an attacker more information than you'd like to give them. A standard example is a file system with a lot of folders, ~20 files each and each file ~3MB, which is easily recognized to be a music CD collection, even if encrypted. Another example is storing a certain set of known files (say a Windows DVD). By looking at the directory structure and file sizes, someone having access to the encrypted files can easily figure out whether your file system contains it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [**Gnome Encfs Manager**](http://www.libertyzero.com/GEncfsM/) project.

It implements an easy GUI way to organize one or multiple EncFS volumes (which you then can sync via Ubuntu One, Dropbox and similar services; maybe WebDAV also works).

Look at **Uli's answer** for the details:

> Yes it is possible. The best way to archieve this with a per file encryption is way is with encfs:
>
> The general principle is that you have a (hidden) encrypted folder inside UbuntuOne/Dropbox where your files are stored, but you access them though another folder, where the decrypted files are shown. Any File you add to the decrypted folder will be encrypted and put into the encrypted folder:
>
> Decrypted folder ←encfs→ Encrypted Folder (inside UbuntuOne/Dropbox)
>
> On another computer the encrypted folder is synced by UbuntuOne/Dropbox and can also be decrypted on the fly.

I think, it's the way you have to think the least. Plus, it is open source.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Gnome Encfs Manager works great and is certainly easier to use. I updated my answer accordingly and also updated the cross platform section to include compatible android apps.

Answer (score 1):

*From [TrueCrupt home page](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/): **WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues.***

---

You can also use **truecrypt**.

Below is a short summary of how can you use *truecrypt* (sources for detailed instructions are provided below):

- Download *truecrypt* from http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads and install it.
- Open *truecrypt* and go to *Volumes* > *Create New Volume*.
- Choose *Create an encrypted file container*.
- Configure the container: place to store the file container, hashing and encryption algorithm, size of the container, passwords/keyfiles etc, and format the container.
- From the main *truecrypt* window, select *File* button to locate the file you've created and press *Mount*.
- Provide your password/keyfiles.
- Now you can see file mounted in *nautilus* or any other file explorer.
- After you're done dismount the volume.

Now, you can upload this volume container to your Ubuntu One account.

***Sources and further information:***

- [Ubuntu Wiki - TrueCrypt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrueCrypt)
- [Official TrueCrypt Tutorial](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=tutorial)
- [Google Groups - encfs vs TrueCrypt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datastorageunit/NhD5LoSSDYA)
- [linux.livejournal.com - encfs vs TrueCrypt](http://linux.livejournal.com/1868082.html)

---

This answer was not intended to be a comparison but below I'm mentioning advantages/disadvantages of using *truecrypt* for reference.

The **advantages** of using *truecrypt* (over *encfs*) are as follows:

- *truecrypt* is cross-platform. It is available for Windows, Linux, and Mac.
- *encfs* uses FUSE to mount an encrypted directory onto another directory and thus file transfer is relatively slow.
- *encfs* is file based. This means that everyone can actually see the number of files, permissions, approximate size, and the last time they were accessed or modified.

The **disadvantages** are:

- The encrypted volume is a fixed size volume, so the file would always occupy the maximum space. Whereas *encfs* uses space when you copy files.
- **ONE BIG DISADVANTAGE:** Whenever you modify the encrypted volume, you'd have to download/upload the complete file to sync your Ubuntu One account.

Comment: Another disadvantage: you get synchronization conflicts in the container file when you don't wait for a full sync in between working on your files with different computers. An alternative would be [Cryfs](https://www.cryfs.org)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu File storage is now dead. 
I use https://syncthing.net/ now.

- Open source.
- Free and unlimited data storage.
- Data is stored only on your devices.