# In which country(s) is our  Ubuntu One data stored?

Tags: ubuntu-one, security

In view of the UK government's new internet snooping proposals can anyone answer this question about the physical location of our data?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I don't believe the answer will mean anything in terms of the UK government proposals.

Answer (score 18):

[Ubuntu One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One) uses [Amazon's S3 service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) in datacenters around the world. There are no UK datacenters listed on S3's website, though this could change.

To answer your question directly, S3 Datacenters (holding your Ubuntu One data) [are in the following countries](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/): USA, Ireland, Singapore, Japan, and Brazil. None of those countries are part of the UK.

If you don't trust one or more of these governments with your data, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75377/encrypting-data-in-ubuntu-one) on encrypting your data in Ubuntu One.

EDIT: [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/TechnicalDetails) is the Ubuntu One technical details page confirming they use S3