# Ubuntu One sync notifications not showing when using Encfs

Tags: ubuntu-one, encfs

I have followed [How can I encrypt data in Ubuntu One or Dropbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75377/encrypting-data-in-ubuntu-one/84543#84543) to set up Ubuntu One with Encfs. It's working well and I can save files on one device and instantly read them on the other. I have verified that the files are truly encrypted by trying to download them from the Ubuntu One web interface.

The only problem is that I am not getting notification messages from Ubuntu One when I add new files or when new files are synced. Also, there are no helpful "Syncing" and "Checked" indicators superimposed over my file's icons so I have no way of knowing when a file has finished syncing.

Have I don't something wrong or missed something in the setup, or is this just a trade-off I have to accept if I want to use Encfs with Ubuntu One?

If it's the latter, are there any alternative ways of encryping on a per-file basis on Ubuntu One?

Comment: Do you have `ubuntuone-client-gnome` installed? And do you have the Ubuntu One notifications disabled? It's an option in the control panel application. Are you running in the standard Unity environment, or have you switched to something else?

Comment: I have everything set up as standard. The notifications and synching/checked indicators work fine for regular files in the Ubuntu One folder. The problem I am having relates specifically to encrypted files on the Encfs mount in my Ubuntu One folder.

Comment: Are you looking in the encrypted folder for the emblems, or the decrypted folder?

Comment: I'm looking at the decrypted folder. The emblems show correctly on the encrypted folder. Sorry, I should have been more clear about this. So I guess my question is: Is there a way for the emblems to be displayed on the decrypted folder and it's contents? Having them on  the encrypted folder is useless because I even have encrypted filenames so the whole lot is meaningless to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are looking at the encrypted folder path to see the emblems. Ubuntu One doesn't know anything about the decrypted mount, so viewing it won't show any emblems. I don't know if there's any good way to go about making that work, technically, either. It may be something that the `gnome-encfs` package might need to provide via a Nautilus extension, showing the same emblems on the decrypted files, that are set on the encrypted files, updating automatically.

As for the notifications, you should be getting them, but they will have the names/paths of the encrypted files, which may also be confusing you if you're expecting the decrypted file names. This is also because Ubuntu One doesn't know anything about the decrypted mount point. I don't think there is any way to work around this technically.

Comment: Thanks @dobey. It doesn't  solve my problem but it answers my question about whether the emblems not displaying is a trade-off when you use encrypted files. They display in the encrypted folder only which is useless because, well, everything is encrypted :-) You're right that the notifications do display but the filenames are encrypted so, again, the notifications don't make much sense. Hopefully Ubuntu One will introduce integrated encryption in the future to make things simpler.